# Error al mostrar un formulario con Thymeleaf

Tags: java, mvc, spring, thymeleaf

estoy intentando mostrar un formulario usando Thymeleaf, usando controladores con el framework Spring, y no para de mostrarme el siguiente error:

> Caused by: org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Could not parse as expression: "@(/new-user)" (template: "/users/registration" - line 12, col 7)

Os dejo por aquí los ficheros, y pantallazos, por si alguién me pudiera echar una mano. Gracias!

**Fichero HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"
      xmlns:th="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>User registration</title>
</head>

<body>

<form th:action="@(/new-user)" th:object="${user}" method="post">

    <label>Usuario</label>
    <input type="text" th:field="*{username}">

    <label>Password</label>
    <input type="text" th:field="*{password}">

    <label>E-mail</label>
    <input type="text" th:field="*{email}">

    <button type="submit">Registrar</button>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Controlador**

```
package com.example.myshop.contoller;

import com.example.myshop.domain.User;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;

@Controller
public class UserController {
    @GetMapping("/registration")
    public String registration(Model model) {
        User user = User.builder().build();
        model.addAttribute("user", user);
        return "/users/registration";
    }

    @GetMapping("/new-user")
    public String newUser(@ModelAttribute User user,
                          Model model) {

        System.out.println("Inserto al usuario por BBDD" + user.getUsername());
        model.addAttribute("reponseOK", "Usuario registrado correctamente");
        return "/users/registration";
    }
}
```

**Estructura del proyecto**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Error que muestra**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes que incluir el namespace correcto:

```
   xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
```

Comment: Era eso! Muchas gracias!